# change the language attrib in HTML tag based on user's language Django Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

how to change the language attribute `<html class="no-js" lang="en">` in HTML tag based on user's language dynamically? in ..

## Django & #Wagtail templates

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`get_current_language`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#get-current-language) tag:

```
<!doctype html>
{% load i18n %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<html class="no-js" lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
```

Comment: what are the differences between :
{% load  i18n  %}
<html class="no-js" lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
------------ &----------
{% load  i18n  %}
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

<html class="no-js" lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}">
----------------
??

Comment: In the first one, you haven't defined the variable LANGUAGE_CODE, so it'll be blank.